# Writing file in android service running in a vehicle or android auto

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-auto

Hello I am trying to create an android service which will act as a black box which records, the GPS location & speed info from the GPS sensor into a csv file in vehicle, the service is started on device boot e.g. when vehicle starts, the complete service code is following

```
public class VehicleBlackBox extends Service implements SimpleLocation.Listener
{
    private final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID;
    private final String channelName;
    private SimpleLocation location;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private final MessageFormat formatter;

    public VehicleBlackBox()
    {
        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.andy.myapplication";
        channelName = "My Background Service";
        formatter = new MessageFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        location = new SimpleLocation(this, true, false, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Notification notification = GenerateNotification();
        startForeground(1337, notification);

        try
        {
            LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.now();
            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String formatedDateTime = current.format(format);
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SweetSwift");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(dir, "Session " + formatedDateTime + ".csv");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fos = null;
            pw = null;
        }

        location.beginUpdates();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        location.endUpdates();

        try
        {
            if(pw != null)
                pw.close();
            if(fos != null)
                fos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stopForeground(true);
    }

    private Notification GenerateNotification(){
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        return new Notification.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Swift Black Box")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setTicker("Your riding session is being monitored for later anaylisis")
                .setSubText("Vehicle driving performance measuring system")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    }

    private void updateTripInfo(double longitude, double latitude, double altitude, double speed, long timestamp)
    {
        if(fos != null && pw != null)
        {
            pw.println(formatter.format(new Object[]{longitude, latitude, altitude, speed, timestamp}));
            pw.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionChanged()
    {
        updateTripInfo(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getSpeed(), location.getTimestampInMilliseconds());
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code but according to my file handling understanding I have following concern.

When vehicle ignition will be turned off e.g., car parked, Android will be simply turned off (full power loss shutdown), that means service onDestroy or any other event won't be called, that way I suspect data will not be saved in csv file as proper file closing skipped due to sudden power off.

I know I can wrap everything in a single function which for every row write will open the file write row and close but for the sake of optimization I don't find this solution feasible or a good one.

Is there anything else that I can do to write to the file safely & reliably.

Comment: On what kind of device is your Android app running?

Comment: `I haven't tested the code` ????????????????????

Comment: @blackapps its a tablet installed in a vehicle, which simply shutdowns on ignition off, for example check this link https://v7traders.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Suzuki-Swift-2008-15-Android-Navigation-Dashboard-V7.jpg

Comment: If you did not try your code... well then it is time you go out for a drive. And see what happens. If you do not want to close the file at every line added you could do it after ever ten. Or whatever you like. You could also as extra add all locations to a SQLiteDatabase. Then you can always after a drive compare the csv file with the data in the base.

Comment: I tested the app on android emulator with GPS fake route added, code is working fine but nothing is saved as for testing i simply turned of my emulator without proper shutdown and voila, file has 0 bytes of data.

Comment: Ok. But an emulator is an emulator and you really should test it on the real device. Doestn't it have a battery? I imagine you take it out of the car to install your app. Is the only power then by usb?

Comment: I will test it tonight, and will let you know about this